# Exception in System.ServiceModel.WasHosting.dll when asking WebService

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-10, httpwebrequest

I'm facing an incomprehensible situation.

I can't totally access to my webservice. When i want to consume my webservice a have this error (this is not in my code but in System.ServiceModel.WasHosting.dll) :

[NullReferenceException: The object reference is not defined to an instance of an object] System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +390
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +175
System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetRouteServiceHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +7
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar) +152 System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +126

My computer : windows 10.

Version Microsoft .NET Framework :4.0.30319; Version ASP.NET :4.7.2556.0

I think this is not a programming error in my code because the webservice work on others computers. this error happens only on my computer.

I find this :https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d72570c0-98ea-41cb-8423-94c96abcb2e8/wcf-service-activation-problem?forum=wcf on the subject but this hotfix isn't for windows 10 and im not sure these two errors are related

Im not asking what is a nullReferenceException but how to fix my problem in System.ServiceModel.WasHosting.dll.

If anyone knows this error please help me.

Comment: The problem with this question is definitely the lack of information and its unsolvable in this state. If it's your webservice, try to debug it from the server side. Check if your Client is sending the correct objects/parameters to the webservice. Then form a clear question with a comprehensible example of the problem and ask again.

Comment: thx for your answer, but i write "the webservice and the client work well on others computers, this error happens only on my computer". i can't be more clear : my problem is an error in System.ServiceModel.WasHosting.dll (windows framework). Maybe another person has already had this problem.

Comment: `"the webservice and the client work well on others computers, this error happens only on my computer` tells us nothing. We don't know your code or the environment. Maybe something is missing on your machine. Only you knows that... or not...

Comment: Don't expect an answer on this... Sorry

Comment: ok thx @Smartis i will ask well again

Answer (score 2):

I was having this exact same problem and have just managed to fix it after wasting many days!

I tried uninstalling all .NET Core / Framework / Visual Studio (I had 2013 - 2019, reinstalled only 2019), .NET repair and uninstall tools etc and was stuck with the exact same problem.

So I figured it must be some sort of IIS express config laying around.... I found and renamed (just incase, seems like it recreates and this can be safely removed) this folder `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress` to `IISExpress.old` , ran my solution.... and it now seems to be working fine!